# Grep a word out of a file and save the file as that word

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, scripting, grep

I am using Ubuntu Linux and grepping info out of a file (lets say filename.log) and want to save the file using some of the info inside of (filename.log).

example:

```
The info in the (filename.log) has version_name and date.
```

When displaying this info on screen using cat it will display:

```
version_name=NAME
date=TODAY
```

I then want to save the file as NAME-TODAY.log and have no idea how to do this.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: I have no idea where to start with this, hence any help or guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can chain a bunch of basic linux commands with the pipe character `|`. Combined with a thing called command substitution (taking the output of a complex command, to use in another command. syntax: `$(your command)`) you can achieve what you want to do.

This is what I came up with, based on your question:

```sh
cp filename.log $(grep -E "(version_name=)|(date=)" filename.log | cut -f 2 -d = | tr '\n' '-' | rev | cut -c 2- | rev).log
```

So here I used `cp`, `$()`, `grep`, `cut`, `tr` and finally `rev`.

Since you said you had no idea where to start, let me walk you trough this oneliner:

1. `cp` - it is used to *copy* the filename.log file to a new file,
   with the name based on the values of `version_name` and `date` (step 2 and up)
2. command substitution `$()` the entire command between the round brackets is 'resolved' before finishing the cp command in step 1. e.g. in your example it would be NAME-TODAY. notice the `.log` at the end outside of the round brackets to give it a proper file extension. The output of this command in your example will be `NAME-TODAY.log`
3. `grep -E "(version_name=)|(date=)"` grep with regexp flag `-E` to be able to do what we are doing. Matches any ***lines*** that contain `version_name=` OR `date=`. The expected output is:

```sh
version_name=NAME
date=TODAY
```

5. `cut -f 2 -d =` because I am not interested in `version_name`
   , but instead in the value associated with that field, I use cut to split the line at the equals character `=` with the flag `-d =`. I then select the value behind the equals character (the second field) with the flag `-f 2`. The expected output is:

```sh
NAME
TODAY
```

6. `tr '\n' '-'` because grep outputs on multiple lines, I want to remove all new lines and replace them with a dash.  Expected output:

```sh
NAME-TODAY-
```

7. `rev | cut -c 2- | rev` I am grouping these. `rev` reverses the word I have created. with `cut -c 2-` I cut away all characters starting from the second character of the reversed word. This is required because I replaced new lines with dashes and this means I now have `NAME-TODAY-`. Basicly this is just an extra step to remove the last dash. See expected outputs of each step:

```
-YADOT-EMAN
```

```
YADOT-EMAN
```

```
NAME-TODAY
```

remember this value is in the command substituion of step 2, so the end result will be:

`cp filename.log NAME-TODAY.log`

Answer (score 0):

I manged to solve this by doing the following: grep filename.log > /tmp/file.info && filename=$(echo $(grep "version_name" /tmp/filename.info | cut -d " " -f 3)-$(grep "date" /tmp/filename.info | cut -d " " -f 3)-$filename.log

Comment: This seems to be a candidate for the Useless Use of echo award: http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#echo